# How to omit escaping "/" in Nlog.Web.AspNetCore

Tags: asp.net-core, nlog

I'm using Nlog.Web.AspNetCore 4.8 to log to a file. In the Nlog.config I've configured the layout as JsonLayout. The problem is that the final outcome contains a backslash to escape the "/" present in the original error message. Is there a way to configure NLog to omit escaping certain characters unless explicitly told so?

Here is my JsonLayout configuration:

```
<target xsi:type="File" name="ownFile-web" fileName="${logDirectory}/logs.txt" >
  <layout type='JsonLayout' includeAllProperties="true"  maxRecursionLimit="20" >
    <attribute name="time" layout="${longdate}" />
    <attribute name="level" layout="${level}" />
    <attribute name="logger" layout="${logger}" />
    <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
  </layout >
</target>
```

And here is the outcome:

```
{ "time": "2019-03-01 01:12:07.2239", "level": "Error", "logger": "Scheduler.Api.Startup", "message": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server\/Instance Specified)" }
```

I would rather the outcome look like this:

```
{ "time": "2019-03-01 01:12:07.2239", "level": "Error", "logger": "Scheduler.Api.Startup", "message": "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an encoding issue. Try the below.

```
 <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" encode="false"/>
```

I would also recommend including the actual exception in your layout file like so

```
 <attribute name="${exception}" layout="${exception:format=toString}" />
```

Comment: @aspdev happy to help!